# What to add to a .gitignore for an Xcode project

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

I have just started a collaborative Xcode project and am running into issues with my collaborators having unintentional changes in their projects. What should I add to my .gitignore for a project like this? I have seen issues with `.xcuserdata` just to give an example.

Answer (score 1):

I've included the .gitignore file used by GitHub, [Objective-C](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore). The parent [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore) repository for .gitignore files is very useful for other languages as well.

```
# Xcode
#
# gitignore contributors: remember to update Global/Xcode.gitignore, Objective-C.gitignore & Swift.gitignore

## User settings
xcuserdata/

## compatibility with Xcode 8 and earlier (ignoring not required starting Xcode 9)
*.xcscmblueprint
*.xccheckout

## compatibility with Xcode 3 and earlier (ignoring not required starting Xcode 4)
build/
DerivedData/
*.moved-aside
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3

## Obj-C/Swift specific
*.hmap

## App packaging
*.ipa
*.dSYM.zip
*.dSYM

# CocoaPods
#
# We recommend against adding the Pods directory to your .gitignore. However
# you should judge for yourself, the pros and cons are mentioned at:
# https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#should-i-check-the-pods-directory-into-source-control
#
# Pods/
#
# Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from the Xcode workspace
# *.xcworkspace

# Carthage
#
# Add this line if you want to avoid checking in source code from Carthage dependencies.
# Carthage/Checkouts

Carthage/Build/

# fastlane
#
# It is recommended to not store the screenshots in the git repo.
# Instead, use fastlane to re-generate the screenshots whenever they are needed.
# For more information about the recommended setup visit:
# https://docs.fastlane.tools/best-practices/source-control/#source-control

fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/Preview.html
fastlane/screenshots/**/*.png
fastlane/test_output

# Code Injection
#
# After new code Injection tools there's a generated folder /iOSInjectionProject
# https://github.com/johnno1962/injectionforxcode

iOSInjectionProject/
```

Answer (score 1):

There're templates available on the Internet. Some of the most famous are

- [github/gitignore templates repo](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Xcode.gitignore)
- [gitignore.io](https://gitignore.io/), which has more templates than the former link.

  - [toptal/gitignore](https://github.com/toptal/gitignore), the templates repo used by gitignore.io
  - [laggardkernel/git-ignore](https://github.com/laggardkernel/git-ignore), ZSH plugin, use the templates from gitignore.io **offline**

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding `.DS_Store` to your .gitignore file as well.